# Intercept-url for all_user and role_user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

if i set intercept-url with filters='none' , everyone can access it but i cannot get SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(), even though, user is logined in. (just exactly mentioned in http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-anon-access-denied )

On the other hand, if i set access='role_user', only authenticated user able to access it.  I want to allow both "not authenticated" and "authenticated" use to access the url  and use 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() to check user is already authenticated. How should i put as parameter in intercept-url ?

Comment: could you please post (the relevant parts) of `web.xml` filter settings and the spring security configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use access "permitAll" in the SPRING Security configuration

Spring configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
   <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
</http>
```

Comment: i tried  <intercept-url pattern="/somepage.jsp" access="permitAll" />
doesnt work. does this work in spring3 ?

Comment: cometta: it should work in Spring 3.0 with Spring Security 3.0

Comment: Did you specify **use-expressions="true"** as shown in the example ?